# How get String before hyphen in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want yo get the first name initial and last name.

Input :

```
<root>
  <ele str="Great Success-Turbo Pat(by Sundon) [Cheeky Pat 8m(Monarchy)"/>
  <ele str="Brylin Boyz-Scallywag"/>
  <ele str="Majestic Son-Be Bee"/>
</root>
```

Output

```
<names>Great Success</name>
<names>Brylin Boyz</name>
<names>Majestic Son</name>
```

Tried Code:

```
<xsl:template match="root/name">
  <names>
    <xsl:value-of select="@str" />
  </name>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using XSLT 2.0. Thank you

Comment: Output which you mentioned in Question part, is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use fn:substring-before() :

```
<xsl:template match="ele">
  <name>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@str, '-')" />
  </name>
</xsl:template>
```